# How to group records in Entity Frameworkk with where clause

Tags: c#, entity-framework

i want to apply where clause on **COLID** column and wish to take the very last value w.r.t that **COLID**, e.g in **COLID 1** case the last returned value should not be **NULL** and in **COLID 2** it would be **30**,   **against each ENTRYID**

[image]

I can do it well in SQL, look at the query and data:

[image]

Comment: Please check out [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). All caps text is harder to read than regular text. Images should be reserved for GUI errors and other cases where text is inadaquate to show the problem. Any code included in your question should be posted as text.

Comment: I am sorry, I will take care next time.

Comment: Did you write any query for this? What's the issue you are facing there? How to decide which is the last value?

Comment: `_IEntryValueRepository.Get(x => entryId.Contains(x.EntryID) && x.ColID == estDelColId && x.ColValueDate != null)
                                                                      .GroupBy(x => x.ColID)
                                                                      .Select(x => x.OrderByDescending(y => y.Created).First())
                                                                      .ToList();`

I used this, please tell me If I am right?

Comment: `entryId` is int collection? for the posted data `ColValueDate` are all null, so the condition `&& x.ColValueDate != null` will not return any data, `Created` not exist in posted data. will be nice if you update the question by what have you tried.

Comment: You be to edit the question and put the code there and also explain what output do you get with this code.

Comment: I have changed the data image in my question.

Comment: Error on my code:

The LINQ expression '(GroupByShaperExpression:\r\nKeySelector: (e.ColID), \r\nElementSelector:(EntityShaperExpression: \r\n    EntityType: EntryValue\r\n    ValueBufferExpression: \r\n        (ProjectionBindingExpression: EmptyProjectionMember)\r\n    IsNullable: False\r\n)\r\n)\r\n    .OrderByDescending(y => y.Created)' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to either AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), or ToListAsync().

Answer (score 0):

You can edit your question to append code rather than pasting it into comments. Paste the code into the question and use the "{}" button in the editor to code format.

You can group and sort items in Linq without too much issue.

```
context.Entries
    .GroupBy(x => x.EntryID)
    .Select(x => x.OrderByDescending(y => y.ColID).FirstOrDefault())
    .ToList();
```

`GroupBy` defines what columns make up the unique grouping. In your case if you want the latest Entry then the EntryId would be enough to define what to group on. This will form the `Key` for each group.  From there we use `Select` to tell it what to select from each group. The group will be all entries of that EntryID so we order by the ColID descending so the biggest one is first, then use `FirstOrDefault` to take the largest one. The `ToList()` at the end materializes the result to retrieve the latest ColID version of each EntryID.

Edit: If you want to only consider non-null values:

```
context.Entries
    .Where(x => x.ColValueId != null)
    .GroupBy(x => x.EntryID)
    .Select(x => x.OrderByDescending(y => y.ColID).FirstOrDefault())
    .ToList();
```

Linq is a bit different than SQL and can have some limitations when used with EF because EF will ultimately need to convert it to SQL.  Still, it is well worth reading up on Linq because it is a very powerful tool when working with objects and it allows EF to do a lot of the heavy lifting.

Comment: So where will I apply the WHERE clause against the ColID and ColValueDate ?

Comment: If you want to filter non-null values for instance then put a `Where` clause before the group by.